# Xcode: keyboard shortcut to navigate to next/previous breakpoint

Tags: swift, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, breakpoints

I thought I remember a keyboard shortcut in Xcode to jump to the next breakpoint in a project. I used this to quickly jump back and forth between two sections of code I was working on. I'm worn out by looking through loads of Google results to no avail. I'm also open to an alternative way to bookmark and navigate between two places in Xcode with a keyboard shortcut. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open Xcode
- Press `command` and `+` at the same time ( or just go to Xcode preferences )
- Choose Key bindings section and write to search bar "step"

You can change as you wish or use default ones.

[image]

Comment: This definitely answered my question...we can't do it that way. The closest thing I found was creating a comment // MARK: - 1 and pressing CTRL+6, 1, Enter